# Grouping Consecutive Numbers on a Dataset in JasperReports (iReport)

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a query in my jasper report and one of its result set generated by the user-given inputs might be those datum stated below:

```
memberId stockNo refineryCode constantSerialNo  serialNo
45       1       IAR          A-                98729
45       1       IAR          A-                98730
45       1       IAR          A-                98731
45       1       IAR          A-                98733
45       1       IAR          A-                98734
45       1       IAR          A-                98736
45       1       IAR          A-                98737
45       1       IAR          A-                98738
45       1       IAR          A-                98739
```

And I want to display those datum on one line if the serialNo's are consecutive. So if I wanna display the above datum in the report, I have to display them in the below stated manner:

```
memberId stockNo refineryCode constantSerialNo  serialNo
45       1       IAR          A-                98729 - 98731
45       1       IAR          A-                98733 - 98734
45       1       IAR          A-                98736 - 98739
```

I know that there might be some solutions using cursor on the sql or using ORM in an OOP language like Java and sending to the jasper report. However, just out of curiosity I'd like to ask whether there may be a dynamic solution using iReport's Expressions or Groups or any other thing that didn't come to my mind now which can make my life easier.

Comment: There is a way in orcale to create a query that would give you a result like that. except it would list SerialNo as 98729,98730,98731

Comment: You are right, there must be a way implementing what I want using query but I want a solution by using jasper reports - iReport.

Comment: You might be able to do it using a pivot table in ireport.

Comment: you mean writing the query and putting them on the report query section in iReport??

Comment: You can get what you want in Oracle SQL.  DOes that solve your problem or do you want to do this on the reporting side?

Comment: @faruk postacioglu that is the easiest solution, but I think making a pivot in Ireport could produce the same result

Comment: @Sibster it would be nice to see the pivot or sql query solution if you could provide one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, assuming `serialNo` is some sort of numerical value and not a String.

1. The dataset of the sql query result has to be ordered by `serialNo`, like you have shown above.
2. Create a `Report Group` with the following group expression: `$V{GroupCount} == new BigDecimal(0) ? $F{serialNo}:$F{serialNo}.subtract($V{GroupCount})`. This will create a new group every time there is a gap in the `serialNo` sequence.
3. Create a variable `GroupCount` that counts the number of consecutive `serialNo` values in the current group. This variable is used to keep track of what the next expected `serialNo` value is.
4. Create a variable `StartRange` that will hold the start value for a given range of consecutive `serialNo` values. The value should reset on the start of a new group and have the following value: `$V{GroupCount}.intValue() == 1 ? $F{ID}:$V{StartRange}`.
5. Set the `Evaluation Time` value of the `serialNo` field to be `ReportGroup`. Put the following value in it: `$V{StartRange}+" - " + $F{serialNo}`.
6. Change the `Print When Expression` of the `Detail` band to the followng: `new Boolean($V{GroupCount}.intValue() == 1)`.

I have posted complete jrxml code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with iReport - A designer for JasperReports -->
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport name="Group_By_Consecutive" columnCount="1" printOrder="Vertical" orientation="Portrait" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" columnSpacing="0" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenNoDataType="NoPages" isTitleNewPage="false" isSummaryNewPage="false">
  <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0" />
  <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <import value="java.util.*" />
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" />
  <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*" />
  <queryString>
    <![CDATA[select 1 as id, 'Name 1' as name from dual union all
select 2 as id, 'Name 2' as name from dual union all
select 3 as id, 'Name 3' as name from dual union all
select 4 as id, 'Name 4' as name from dual union all
select 6 as id, 'Name 6' as name from dual union all
select 7 as id, 'Name 7' as name from dual union all
select 8 as id, 'Name 8' as name from dual union all
select 9 as id, 'Name 9' as name from dual union all
select 10 as id, 'Name 10' as name from dual union all
select 11 as id, 'Name 11' as name from dual union all
select 14 as id, 'Name 14' as name from dual union all
select 15 as id, 'Name 15' as name from dual union all
select 16 as id, 'Name 16' as name from dual union all
select 17 as id, 'Name 17' as name from dual union all
select 23 as id, 'Name 23' as name from dual union all
select 24 as id, 'Name 24' as name from dual union all
select 25 as id, 'Name 25' as name from dual union all
select 26 as id, 'Name 26' as name from dual union all
select 27 as id, 'Name 27' as name from dual union all
select 28 as id, 'Name 28' as name from dual]]>
</queryString>
  <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
  <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String" />
  <variable name="GroupCount" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Consecutive" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{ID}]]>
</variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression>
      <![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]>
</initialValueExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="StartRange" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$V{GroupCount}.intValue() == 1 ? $F{ID}:$V{StartRange}]]>
</variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <group name="Consecutive">
    <groupExpression>
      <![CDATA[$V{GroupCount} == new BigDecimal(0) ? $F{ID}:$F{ID}.subtract($V{GroupCount})]]>
</groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
      <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
      <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
    </groupFooter>
  </group>
  <background>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </background>
  <title>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </title>
  <pageHeader>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </pageHeader>
  <columnHeader>
    <band height="18" isSplitAllowed="true">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="18" key="staticText-1" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[serialNo]]>
</text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="18" key="staticText-3" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Name]]>
</text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="18" key="staticText-4" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[MetaData(Ignore)]]>
</text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </columnHeader>
  <detail>
    <band height="18" isSplitAllowed="true">
      <printWhenExpression>
        <![CDATA[new Boolean($V{GroupCount}.intValue() == 1)]]>
</printWhenExpression>
      <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self">
        <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="18" key="textField" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
          <![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" pattern="##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="Consecutive" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self">
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="18" key="textField" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
          <![CDATA[$V{StartRange}+" - " + $F{ID}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" pattern="##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self">
        <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="18" key="textField" />
        <box></box>
        <textElement>
          <font />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal">
          <![CDATA[$V{GroupCount}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </band>
  </detail>
  <columnFooter>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </columnFooter>
  <pageFooter>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </pageFooter>
  <summary>
    <band height="0" isSplitAllowed="true"></band>
  </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: That is pretty impressive, and creative on your part. Only thing is to change the first Textfield column to `$V{StartRange} == $F{ID} ? $F{ID}.toString() : $V{StartRange}+" - " + $F{ID}` for when there is just one item in the group it doesn't print the dash. To see what I mean take out the select for id 10. That will give you 11 in a group by it's self.

Comment: Also since you just print the first item in the group the GroupCount column always has 1, but I do not think that matters in this case, as we do not really care how many items are in the group.

Comment: @jschoen nice catch, I never thought about that case.